# AmbiguousMatchException when working with select2 control in javascript

Tags: c#, ui-select2

I have already looked into many other posts on `AmbiguousMatchException` but don't know how to solve my problem. I have a POCO similar to the below class which I use for the front end by serializing it to java script using web api

```
 Class Class1
 {
     public string ID { get; set; }
     public string id { get; set; }
 }
```

I am having these two properties of same name but different cases because ID was there forever and the property id is included to make it work with Select2 control which expects this property in java script. However, when this object is deserialized from json to a c# object using

```
 var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 jss.Deserialize(json.ToString(), Type.GetType(ClassName));
```

where json is a dynamic object

I get error saying the property name is ambiguous. I cannot remove ID because it is there in so many other places where the property is hard coded, but I am also not able to make select2 work without id. How can I make all these work together

Answer (score 0):

you have to try below menioned class it may help you

```
 Class Class1
{
 [JsonProperty("ID")]
 public string ID { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("id")]
 public string secondid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please take a look I have edited the question, The desrializer I'm using is part of the in-built .net json serialzer however JsonProperty is part of NewtonSoft json serializer